# Composite variables in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am doing an analysis of latent constructs.  I was wondering whether it was acceptable to use composite variables given that the measures associated with each of the latent constructs uses up to 80 items?

Answer (score 1):

80 items is a lot, but combining a measurement model with a path model is the very strength of a structural equation model (SEM). So by adding a composite variable, and thus remove the measurement model from your SEM, you lose one of the major advantages of a SEM.

Comment: Would it be acceptable compromise to enter a composite variable and then create a single latent variable in relation to the composite variable?

Comment: Not really, it would just complicate your model without any benefit. The point of a measurement model is that it allows you control for measurement error. If you only add a composite variable you loose all the information present in the data that allows you to estimate that measurement error. So I would not do that.